# Placeholder image loads forever when implementing FadeInImage

Tags: flutter

I'm using FadeInImage.assetNetWork to load an image but the placeholder image("assets/giphy.gif) can't stop so that the image("assets/logo2.png") appears. giphy.gif loads forever

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
          fadeInDuration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
          placeholder: "assets/giphy.gif",
          image: "assets/logo2.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to provide a fade in curve if you set the fade in duration:

```
fadeInCurve: Curves.easeIn,
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe FadeInImage.assetNetwork is meant to load ASSET placeholder and NETWORK image.
If you are loading asset image then it will not work as expected.

I have tried the same and it worked in the local web app but did not work in live server.

I believe "FadeInImage.assetNetwork" was originally designed to load network image as there could be a network lag.

I have tried this in the latest flutter stable 2.0.0